# Declare another object output stream similar to cout

Tags: c++, cout

I'm just curious whether it is possible to somehow declare something similar to cout but to define its function. For example:

```
SetCursorPosition(output_handle, some_COORD);
cout_coord << "Hi\nthere!";
```

to produce this **output**:

```
 .
               Hi
               there!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use operator overloading to make `<<` do basically anything (just google "c++ operator overloading", you'll find tons of information), but such a thing as in your question is generally considered **abuse of operator overloading**. Overloading operators is intended to make code easier to read. In C++, everyone knows that `<<` means "output something", just like `+=` means "mathematically add something" and `=` means "assign something".

When I see `<<` in some piece of code, then I certainly don't read it as "set cursor position and then print text". You could implement it like this, but it's bad programming style, akin to misnaming ordinary functions.

Comment: In C++, everyone knows that `<<` means "left shift".

Comment: A better way to implement this without mucking around with operators is to create an `ostream` wrapper that formats the output and exposes member functions that allow formatting options to be set, or perhaps uses custom manipulators. A simpler way, depending on requirements, is to just use existing manipulators, like `width()` and the alignment ones.

Answer (score 0):

Well cout isn't a function, it's actually a std::ostream. You can create your own ostream that writes to stdout.

Answer (score 0):

The way to implement this logic is to create a custom stream buffer which writes at the opportune location in its `overflow()` method and then to create a suitable `std::ostream` using this stream buffer. Here is a rough sketch on how that would look like:

```
class posbuf: public std::streambuf {
    int d_row;     // current row
    int d_column;  // column where to start output
    void move() { /* use curses, VT100 codes, whatever to move the cursor */ }
    int overflow(int c) {
        if (c == traits_type::eof()) { return traits_type::not_eof(c); }
        if (c == '\n') { ++this->d_row; this->move(); return '\n'; }
        return std::cout << traits_type::to_char_type(c)? c: traits_type::eof();
    }
    int sync() {
        return std::cout.flush()? 0: -1;
    }
public:
    posbuf(int row, int column): d_row(row), d_column(column) { this->move(); }
};
struct oposstream: private virtual posbuf, public std::ostream {
    oposstream(int row, int column): posbuf(row,c column), std::ostream(this) {}
};

int main() {
    oposstream out(4, 10);
    out << "hello\nworld";
}
```

Except for a couple of likely typos and the details on how to actually move the cursor, the above code should actually work and create an `std::ostream` which can be passed wherever an `std::ostream&` is expected. Any attempt to overload the output operator using some templates will not work as well.

Comment: This is interesting but looks a bit complex, I haven't finished the c++ book and I am not that familiar with some of the functions you use. I WILL look them up but actually I found what I was looking, see my answer on the question.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Christian Hackl and another user that removed their answer I did a research and found the answer I was looking for.

If anyone is still curious my example in the question became:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& left, const char * right)
{
    string sRight = right;
    CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO con;
    GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), &con);
    COORD xy;
    xy.X = con.dwCursorPosition.X;
    xy.Y = con.dwCursorPosition.Y;
    for (int i = 0; i < sRight.length(); i++)
    {
        if (sRight[i] == '\n')
        {
            xy.Y++;
            SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), xy);                
            continue;
        }
        cout << sRight[i];
    }
    return left;
}
```

And then you just:

```
SetConsoleCursorPosition(output_handle, some_COORD);
cout_coord << "Hi\nthere!";
```

And "Hi" and "there!" are one under the other for every x given with some_COORD!